# Using pandas cell as a key

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a df where each row has a code that indicates a department.

On the other hand, I have a dictionary in which each code corresponds to a region name (a region is constituted of multiple departments).

I thought of a loop to put the value in a new column that indicates the region.

Here is what I thought would work:

```
for r in df:
    dep = r["dep"].astype(str)
    r["region"] = dep_dict.get(dep)
```

But the only thing I get is "string indices must be integers".
Do you people know how could I make it work ? Or if I should take a totally different route (like joining) ?

Thanks !

Comment: The `r` in `for r in df` is a column header (which is a string, in your case). So, `r["dep"]` is an attempt to index a string with a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.region =  df.dep.apply(lambda x: dep_dict[x])
```

Would this help?